# EF Core: Add custom LINQ in Up method of Migration class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to execute some LINQ in Up method of migrations. Problem is I don't know how can I get DbContext instance?

This is code generated by `migrations add`:

```
public partial class MyTableAddFieldTitle : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "Title",
            table: "MyTable",
            nullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Title",
            table: "MyTable");
    }
}
```

I would like to add something like that in `Up` method:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
        name: "Title",
        table: "MyTable",
        nullable: true);

    var context = ?????;

    //Actual code is much more complicated, but the principle is the same.
    foreach (var item in context.Set<DbMyTable>())
      item.Title = item.SomeStringColumn;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Problem is how to get context instance? I tried with DI in constructor:

```
protected MyTableAddFieldTitle(MyContext context)
{
}
```

but I get error:

> MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object. System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, bool
>   publicOnly, ref bool canBeCached, ref RuntimeMethodHandleInternal
>   ctor)

Comment: Are you mixing seeding and migration? Usually, you wouldn't want to deal with your `DbContext` in the migration stage as it's just being built. If you need to seed data, do it properly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: Maybe, but I think not. I just created new field on a table. I need to populate this field. I understand seeding as a way to fill database with some records. I will take a look. Thanks for now.

Comment: @haim770 You were right. In Up method  field `Title` doesn't yet exists on database.

Comment: Of course it doesn't exist. Migrations just create the necessary abstract operations needed. Think of them as migration command builders. Thus you are limited to the available commands, with `Sql` being the only method allowing you to specify arbitrary SQL command(s). No LINQ, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution.

In `Startup` class I defined static variable:

```
public static Func<MyContext> ContextFactory;
```

In constructor of `Startup` class I assigned variable:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration config)
{
    MyContext GetContext(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:Web"], b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Web.Hosting"));
        if (environment.IsDevelopment())
            builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        return new MyContext(builder.Options);
    }

    ContextFactory = () => GetContext(config, env);
}
```

Then in Migrations I simply call `ContextFactory`:

```
var context = Startup.ContextFactory();
context.Set<DbMyTable>().Where(....
```

To avoid error field does not exists I create 2 migration files (`dotnet ef migrations add`).
First adds field:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
        name: "Title",
        table: "MyTable",
        nullable: true);
}
```

And second (empty) executes query:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    var context = Startup.ContextFactory();
    context.Set<DbMyTable>().Where(....
}
```